# In theory, what is the maximum practical level for skills and attributes in Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Given free use of the console to increase skills and attributes and objects/other effects held, used, obtained or invoked (e.g. a Fortify Attribute from a spell or birthsign) is there a maximum level that is practically used in-game for skills or attributes?

In this context I mean "practically" to mean "affects the game", in terms of beyond the number displayed on the screen.

As far as I understand it skills can be set up an absolute maximum of 100 and nothing will make it higher (in terms of gameplay), whilst attributes can go over 100 although I don't know if it will be practically useful in the game.

I suppose one way to phrase my question would be "what is the highest the numbers can go on the screen" combined with "what is the best effective possible character the game can support, judged by skill/attribute stats alone"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Oblivion Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Skills):

> Some magical effects can increase your skill above 100, but in general increases above 100 have no real effect. The only exceptions are Acrobatics and Athletics , which will continue to increase your character's jump height and run speed, respectively, up to a maximum value of 255.

As for [attributes](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Attributes):

> The current value of an attribute can be boosted past 100, and many, but not all, benefits of the attribute continue to increase for values greater than 100 (see Magical Effects on Attributes ). Most aspects of game play are based upon the current value of the attribute. 
>   Fortifying an attribute temporarily raises that attribute's value by M points, for a period of D seconds. Fortify Attribute can increase an attribute above its base value and can even increase an attribute above the maximum value of 100. Increases in attributes past 100 have the same effect as below 100 with one exception: weapon damage. Luck's effect on other attributes of +5 Luck = +2 (Other Attribute) is not altered when Luck is above 100; however, as it effectively raises the level of other skills up to a cap of 100, Luck has a diminishing effect on attributes that exceed the cap, and ceases to have an effect on attributes that reach 100. See Oblivion:Luck and the other attribute pages for details of their effects on skills.

So while fortifying endurance past 100 will boost your health, fortifying strength past 100 will not boost your melee damage but it WILL continue to increase the maximum carry weight and fatigue.

Comment: So the answer to the question for skills would be "Practical maximum for skills is 100, except Acrobatics/Athletics which are 255, the actual maximum for skills", as in your answer above, but I can't see a practical or actual maximum for attributes, only that some benefits apply over 100. I will assume that all attributes have some practical effect up to 255 (also assuming an 8-bit value like skills), but anyone can feel free to put me right on this.

Comment: @kinofrost - You're pretty-much correct. Attributes function normally (or rather, "as expected") for values greater than 100, with the *sole* exception that combat damage calculations cap out at 100 Strength or Agility respectively (spell damage isn't based on a stat).